# Mootools and ExtJs 4.x seem to be incompatible, how to solve?

Tags: extjs, mootools, extjs4.1, compatibility, extjs4.2

Mootools and ExtJs have a compatibility issue when used on the same page. Mootools throws the following error :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Property 'id' of object #<HTMLDocument> is not a function
```

How can we use both frameworks side by side ? Is there a workaround ?

Comment: Nice you got it working! +1 for unusual question

Comment: what is the reason to use both on the same page? Seems like an overkill, no?

Comment: @dbrin I try to upgrade an application that was written using a legacy framework ( jxlib, based on mootools ) in place and step by step. This involves rewriting all javascript, and I hope to be able to leave a part of the app as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a `document.id('..')` reference issue, it is defined but it's not the mootools method...

Nothing will work if it's not pointed to the mootools method.

I would argue that ExtJS or your app has added a property `id` to document, which is not a function as is likely a String or another primitive.

Pretty sure that ExtJS would not have been overwriting `document.id`, especially given that they (Sencha) employed MooTools core team dev @subtlegradient (thomas aylott) who co-wrote the Slick selector engine and helped engineer the `document.id` transition in MooTools from the simple $ in 1.11

You probably cannot do `document.id = $` to restore it as it's by reference and it's been overwritten.

Only chance is to try loading MooTools after ExtJS is loaded and started - or load MooTools, save a ref like `document.$id = document.id;` immediately after, load ExtJS and then restore it back when ready via `document.id = document.$id; delete document.$id` - still no guarantees this will run at the right time. you really need to see what modifies your `document` object in web inspector (you can add a watcher)